# Libre Office Impress opens in 11.10, but not in the launcher

Tags: launcher, libreoffice

I double click my presentation to open it w/Impress and it opens, but there is no icon in the launcher (or alt-tab switcher) to indicate that its open. I tried keeping the Impress icon in the launcher, then opening my presentation, but the same thing happened. Then I tried opening Impress from the launcher and opening my file from inside impress...no luck either. What's up with that?

btw, im using 11.10 and the file was made with office 2010 and saved as a .ppt if that has anything to do with it.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well apparently it had to do with the lo-menubar package. I uninstalled that and it works. Atleast it worked for me, apparently there is another bug

Answer (score 2):

It's an annoying bug.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/1026426